# Embedded video within responsive columns disappears in WebKit

Tags: css, video, multiple-columns

I have been struggling with placing a YouTube video within a responsive CSS column with other content. I have used the recommended fix for responsive video scaling from CSS Tricks and other places. It works fine in Firefox, but the video disappears in Chrome and Safari. I have also tried using http://fitvidsjs.com but without success. Does anyone know of a way to get videos to appear properly within a CSS column with other content? I have also tried to work with other embedded non-video content (Issuu.com publications) and had the same problem.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```
#content {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
*zoom: 1;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#content .content-columns {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
width: 90%;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-moz-column-rule: 1px solid #ECECFB;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #ECECFB;
column-rule: 1px solid #ECECFB;
-moz-column-gap: 26px;
-webkit-column-gap: 26px;
column-gap: 26px;
}

.mod-embed-video{
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.mod-embed-video iframe, .mod-embed-video object, .mod-embed-video embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<div id="content"> 
 <div class="content-columns">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quodsi salutandi at mel, dicam accusamus ut mel. Tation omittam singulis nec no. Ea mea ludus corpora efficiendi. Vel id nihil legendos pertinacia, prima vocibus ut usu. Omnis delicata ut sea, lorem philosophia ex eos, an elit accommodare quo.</p>
  <p>Et vim vero assum error. Sumo tantas an sit, magna dicta an mel, ut wisi feugait consequat eum. An ius recteque dignissim assueverit. Ius homero populo expetenda te, an sit amet possit pertinacia. Sed aeterno perpetua ea. Eam cu ullum dicta, commodo appareat id pro.</p>
  <p>Mea cu commodo aeterno labitur, ius dolorem intellegat disputando ea, cum eros harum no. Errem principes delicatissimi in vel. Evertitur forensibus eu sea, te has eirmod tractatos consetetur. Te has vitae mandamus suscipiantur, duo labores mentitum principes eu.</p>
  <p>Ad elitr vocibus vim, agam oportere est et, his eu elit facilisi tacimates. Soleat torquatos deterruisset mel ut, in tollit ocurreret his, vis et nulla epicurei vituperata. Tation euismod accusam sea in, sed modo dico ut. Pri ignota putant iudicabit ex.</p>
  <p>Et vim vero assum error. Sumo tantas an sit, magna dicta an mel, ut wisi feugait consequat eum. An ius recteque dignissim assueverit. Ius homero populo expetenda te, an sit amet possit pertinacia. Sed aeterno perpetua ea. Eam cu ullum dicta, commodo appareat id pro.</p>
  <div class="mod-embed-video">
   <iframe width="550" height="309" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9-5MVFMWSh0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <p>Et vim vero assum error. Sumo tantas an sit, magna dicta an mel, ut wisi feugait consequat eum. An ius recteque dignissim assueverit. Ius homero populo expetenda te, an sit amet possit pertinacia. Sed aeterno perpetua ea. Eam cu ullum dicta, commodo appareat id pro.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you use *float:left* and it breaks your responsive iframe approach because position is set to absolute, therefore you get nothing. You need to find another solution where either you use another approach for columns, probably using Jquery, because column-count won't work and quite honestly I can't think of any pure html5+css approach that will allow automatic columns + responsive video